# Margens em CSS usando jquery-mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Não estou a conseguir criar margens usando css em uma pagina html usando jquery-mobile quando o header e o footer é `data-position="fixed"`.

O meu exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/z2z7zjvL/

```css
.ui-header, .ui-footer, .ui-content {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>My header</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Content goes here..</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>My footer</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
```

Como resolver isto quando preciso que o header e o footer sejam fixas?

Comment: ola amigo seria isso que esta procurando fazer? http://jsfiddle.net/z2z7zjvL/3/ nesse link voce encontra mais referencias: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

Comment: Não sei se reparou mas a margem direita não está a funcionar direito. Esse é o problema para qual eu não arranjo solução.

Answer (score -1):

Confere se funciona para você:

```
<style>
.ui-header, .ui-footer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.ui-content {
  margin: 20px;
}
</style>

<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
    <h1>My header</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p> <p>Content goes here..</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
    <h1>My footer</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>

</html>
```